# nohup command not able print the output to nohup.out

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java

I wrote a bash script to execute my jar file in ubuntu or Red Hat environment. Here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
$nohup java -jar /home/chikin/Downloads/hardcoded.jar & tail -f nohup.out
```

My bash script will execute the jar that i had developed, i hope to print out the output from the jar file into `nohup.out` or any txt file,so i can trace out any problem easily but it's seem like no printing out anything when i execute the script, it's print out all the output in terminal. But when i execute  `nohup java -jar /home/chikin/Downloads/hardcoded.jar &` directly from the terminal, it's able to print all the jar output into nohup.out. May i know why my script not working ? 
    My script also not able to trigger every time i reboot my ubuntu machine, i tested many of the solutions but none of them working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have exported the value of `nohup` into the script's environment (e.g. `export nohup=/usr/bin/nohup`) then `$nohup` will evaluate to the empty string - hence your command

```
$nohup java -jar /home/chikin/Downloads/hardcoded.jar
```

becomes plain

```
java -jar /home/chikin/Downloads/hardcoded.jar
```

so `nohup` is not being invoked at all. You probably want

```
nohup java -jar /home/chikin/Downloads/hardcoded.jar & tail -f nohup.out
```

(without the `$`).

---

Probably it's better to make the output file explicit:

```
nohup java -jar /home/chikin/Downloads/hardcoded.jar > nohup.out & tail -f nohup.out
```

since as noted in the manpage, the rules for the output file depend on whether standard output is a terminal or not:

```
If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if  pos‐
sible,  '$HOME/nohup.out'  otherwise.  If standard error is a terminal,
redirect it to standard output.  To save output  to  FILE,  use  'nohup
COMMAND > FILE'.
```

Comment: any idea how to trigger my script after i reboot my machine ? i tested various method but none of it working, not sure i am misunderstanding any on-line available tutorial

Comment: thanks for your guide, i am able to print my output into nohup.out

Comment: @attack there are several places to run scripts (at boot; when the display manager starts; when a user logs in; when a user's desktop session starts) - the appropriate place will depend what your script does and what environment and resources it needs in order to function correctly

Comment: let me explain what my program will do, my program is a log file analysis program, i will use my script to trigger it to execute as a background service, so i cant wait until user log in